# Displaying different types of items in the ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

Is it possible to use different templates for items in the ListBox in WPF basing on type of item?

Say, we have base class:

```
class BaseItem
{
}
```

And then two more:

```
class IntItem : BaseItem
{
     public int I { get; set; }
}

class StringItem : BaseItem
{
     public string S { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I may build an `ObservableCollection` of `BaseItem`s and attach to the ListBox. I would like to display the text as a textbox and the integer as a tracker, for instance. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Hallelujah, its possible. :)

Comment: Awww keeey, do I *really* have to rewrite the question? :)

Comment: You can specify a DataTemplate for each different item type , 
just dont provide a specific ItemTempalte for your ItemsControl.

Comment: Mr Spook, just define desired DataTemplates.

Comment: O gosh, it's *that* simple? o_O

Comment: Yeah simply add `DataTemplates` in your ListBox Resources for different data types.

Comment: And if that is not sufficient, e.g. you need different data templates for different items of the same type, you may set the ListBox's [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is possible.

Just define a `DataTemplate` for each `Type` in your ListBox Resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type IntItem}">
    ....
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type StringItem}">
    ....
</DataTemplate>
```